# How to access classes using kivy?

Tags: python, kivy-language

How to access a class in python code using `on_release`: by kivy? For example, a function that is in root I use. `root.function()` and a class?

```
on_release: # What to put here to access the function `chama`?

class Tela(ScreenManager):
    pass
class teste(Screen):
    def chama(self):
        pass
    def save_d(self):

class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tela()

Prg().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use kv (file or string), then a good way to access other classes is to use ids.
Here is an example:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Tela(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Teste(Screen):
    def chama(self):
        print ('Hello')

class Teste2(Screen):
    pass

class PrgApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Prg.kv')

PrgApp().run()
```

Prg.kv:

```
Tela
    Teste2
        Button
            on_release: t.chama()

    Teste
        id: t
```

note: the first letter of a widget class must be capitalized, otherwise you will get a syntax error